# NestJS Reading File - No Such File or Directory

Tags: node.js, express, nestjs, nestjs-config, fireblocks-sdk

I am having trouble getting my nestJS app to read my cert secret file and even a simple txt file. I am getting the error:

> ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] ENOENT: no such file or directory

Below is all I am doing, using fs to read the file:

```
import {FireblocksSDK, PeerType, TransactionArguments, TransactionOperation, TransactionStatus} from "fireblocks-sdk";
import fs = require('fs');
import path = require('path');

function fireblocks() {
    const text = fs.readFileSync(('./data.txt'), 'utf8');
    console.log(text);
    const apiSecret = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, "../../certs/fireblocks_secret.key"), "utf8");
    return new FireblocksSDK(apiSecret, process.env.FIREBLOCKS_ACCESS_TOKEN);
}
```

Below is my file structure I am using:

> ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] ENOENT: no such file or directory

[image]

Comment: see what's the output of `path.resolve(...)` and you'll find out that the file doesn't exists

Comment: __dirname is /dist for me, need use process.cwd()

Answer (score 6):

[Michael Levi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5290447/micael-levi) recommended `path.join(process.cwd(), ...)` in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72809010/nestjs-reading-file-no-such-file-or-directory#comment128602638_72809010).

So, to read in the cert file in NestJS, I used the line below:

```
 const apiSecret = fs.readFileSync(join(process.cwd(), './src/services/fireblocks/fireblocks_secret.key')).toString();
```

Answer (score 2):

Michael Levi's recommendation, it worked for me in my project and I applied it in this way as I import a json file:

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
import * as path from 'path';
const filePath = path.join(process.cwd(), './src/api/send-message/conf/conf.json');
const configFIle = fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf-8').toString();
export const config = JSON.parse(configFIle);
```